How to load shaders in a game engine asset loading system?
I am making an asset loading system for my game engine, which is written in C++, and the idea I had in mind is that for each asset there is a corresponding loader class. Although not entirely the same the idea was sparked from this thread.
static std::shared_ptr<Mesh> load(const fs::path& path) {
    AssetManager::getAssetData(); // loads the raw data either from disk, network, etc
    AssetManager::create<AssetType>() // instantiates the asset and caches/registers it so it can be retrieved later AssetManager::get()
}

std::shared_ptr<Mesh> myMesh = MeshLoader::load("path/to/mesh.obj");

I've tried to make every loader sort of align with this structure and for the most part it was working fine, but I am facing some challenges applying it to shaders. The problem that I'm finding with them is that since they require multiple files how do you...handle that? I could do ShaderLoader::load(path_to_vertex, path_to_fragment), but the problem with this is that I am making an editor and I want to load assets by drag and dropping the file which as far as I know can only processes 1 file at a time.
The only solution I can think of is instead of trying to load and create the asset in a single step, I make it a 2-step process by loading the asset data and then creating the asset.
auto vertexSource = ShaderLoader::load("path/to/vertex.vert");
auto fragmentSource = ShaderLoader::load("path/to/fragment.frag");
std::shared_ptr<ShaderProgram> shaderProgram = AssetManager::create<ShaderProgram>();
shaderProgram->setVertexSource(vertexSource); 
shaderProgram->setFragmentSource(fragmentSource);

Ultimately I'd just like to know if this is practical or is there a more practical way that  I have not considered?

Did you think about a shader as one resource unit, you have to link shaders into a shader program. So it could be that, when you drag and drop the file, it gives you just a shader resource, and then you have to compose a shader program with a combination of shaders and defining on which stage they are. The stage you can recognize by extension, like vsh for vertex, fsh for fragment or, for example, you can open a context menu on file drop to provide user a way to choose a linkage stage for a given shader file. Have look at different implementations, like in https://github.com/houmain/gpupad

its possible to combine the two files as just one file...
